# how to change links in a xml or any other file with regex or some other way?

Tags: regex, shell, replace, find

I have a file with a lot of xml nodes and they are linked together with an id. I need to change the id of a node as well as the link.

```
 <event id="12345">
     <action>6789</action>
 </event>
 <action id="6789">
     <name>pre-filter1</name>
     <someotherlink>45678</someotherlink>
 </action>
```

I need to change the id of action nodes and the reference wherever it is being linked from. I was looking into regex because I have to do it for some action nodes only with some specific name like pre-filter here. the id needs to be processed by some logic before replacing with the new value. the order of nodes is random.
I only need to do it once for the whole file and any way is fine. also time complexity is not a constraint.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl supports using functions on the replacement of a regular expression. Not sure about other languages.

If you are not using perl, you may do the following:

1) Get all action ids for a given name with this regexp:

```
<action\s*id="(\d+)">(?=[^=]*<name>pre-filter\d<\/name>).*?<\/action>
```

https://regex101.com/r/Q7lKgx/1

2) Convert values and store both original id and converted value in a hash.

3) Loop the hash and use a regexp to replace the id with the new value

This matches both action and action id:

```
(<action(?:\s*id="|>))(THE_ID)("|<\/action)> ==> replace with \1NEW_ID\3
```

Anyways, parsing XML with regexes is usually not a good idea, so It would be even better to use some library to parse xmls.

Comment: But I need to replace both the ids with value I calculate from the parsed value. so simple regex is not enough

Comment: @AntarikshaYelkawar, OK, I edited my answer. Basically you either use a language that supports functions on regular expression replacements, or do several steps